# voipmonitor compile error in Centos7

Tags: compilation, voip, wireshark, recording

I am trying to compile open source software "VoipMonitor" in Centos7 
which is available at this link : http://www.voipmonitor.org 
I've installed all prerequisites but I get following error when running
'Make' command :

`wireshark.cpp:15:41: fatal error: wireshark/wsutil/privileges.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [wireshark.o] Error 1`

anyone know how to install wireshark or any package to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
yum install -y wireshark
```